# modal doesnt get different id

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have number of buttons that open the same bootstrap modal. 
Does the script files (JS) need to be called from the main file or from the modal file?

I'm calling the js files inside the modal, include the "jquery-1.11.1.min.js" file and because of that the id that only the first id that i'm sending to the modal is caught.
I made example:

http://80.179.226.44/~israelig/sites/exmytrip/tempFile.php 
( try to click more than one time)

I need the "jquery-1.11.1.min.js" inside the modal because i want the "upload images" script to work

I need different the id to be sending to the modal. how can i fix that?

main file:

```
<li><a href="modalFile.php?id=1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Send value "1" to modal</a></li>
<li><a href="modalFile.php?id=2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Send value "2" to modal</a></li>
<li><a href="modalFile.php?id=3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Send value "3" to modal</a></li>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Title for modal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

<script>
    // clear model content
    $('body').on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
</script>
```

modal code you can see here:

http://80.179.226.44/~israelig/sites/exmytrip/modalFile.php?id=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `href="url"` I usually set `href="javascript:;"` now use a data attribute eg `data-id="1"` now you need to do something like this
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var id= button.data('id') // Extract info from data-* attributes

  //I'm guess that you want some dynamic content - so perhaps an ajax call and replace your elements

})
```

Yeah and then you can either use the `id` to replace a element or set a value. Or perhaps send an ajax call to get some more complex content. If you are doing an ajax call have a loading bar to help uses - that is shown when you load and hidden after loading. You can make one here http://www.ajaxload.info/